# Exceptions inside exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, exception

When working with C# or Java, I used to create exception classes that included other exceptions as class members. For instance:

```
public class MyException : Exception {
    private MyException ex;
    private String message;

    public String what() {
        return this.message;
    }

    public String stack() {
        if(ex != null) {
            StringBuilder s;
            s.append(this.what());
            s.append(this.ex.stack());
            return s.toString();
        }

        return this.what();
    }
}
```

I was looking for examples on the same subject but for C++ and I couldn't find any (maybe I didn't search for the right terms, as you can see the title of this question is not very fancy).

Anyway, what is the correct way of doing that in C++? Is it to store the inner exception as a pointer or a reference? (I think I might need a pointer so it can be null when it's the first exception). When I raise the exception, should it be as a pointer created with `new`?

EDIT: Maybe what I wrote was a little confusing or not a well-known (-accepted) programming practice. So I'll specify how I intended to use this class with a snippet:

```
 try {
     // Code that throws an exception of type MyException
 } catch(MyException ex) {
     MyException another = new MyException();
     another.setEx(ex);
     another.setMessage("A message that explains where the other exception was caught and on what conditions");

     throw another;
 }
```

Comment: you can't have multiple exceptions in C++. If a new exception is thrown before the current  exception is caught, the program is terminated (more precisely `std::terminate` is called)

Comment: @Gene: This is a variation on rethrow, where the existing exception is stuffed inside a new exception.  Probably not feasible without garbage collection.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Probably feasible without garbage collection if it weren't so hard to remember exactly when exceptions get their destructors called.

Comment: @Dietrich: That is the difficulty.

Comment: @BenVoight GC is a red-herring. Cloning works too, and is available with C++0x.

Comment: @Luc: You can't clone an arbitrary exception.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, `std::current_exception` doesn't guarantee cloning, but it doesn't forbid it. In any case it's good enough for the job.

Comment: @Luc: Note that all of these options are much more complicated than the method when GC is available, in which case you just throw a pointer to a GC-managed exception of any type.

Comment: @BenVoigt GC not much more complicated than the library solution of Boost.Exception :) ? It makes sense if the collector comes for free with your runtime yes, but I wouldn't plug a collector just so I can get nested exceptions.

Comment: @Luc: Right, the question asked whether C++ can do this the same way C# and Java do, and both of those have ubiquitous GC and use it for extending the life of a caught exception.

Answer (score 22):

There is no correct way to do it with the standard exceptions in C++03 because they're designed to be used polymorphically but can't be cloned. So if you catch `std::exception const& e` you *could* store a copy but this will lead to slicing, losing all useful information. You should **not** store a pointer or reference to the exception because its lifetime will come to an end as soon as leaving the `catch` clause (assuming you don't rethrow the original exception).

You could get around this limitation if you knew each and every type that can be thrown and testing them all but that's not a nice design (i.e. it subverts polymorphism). It makes more sense to write a base exception class of your own that can be cloned, and catch that. You still have the problem if you catch an `std::exception` that came from someone else's code however.

At this point I feel compelled to mention [Boost.Exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html). It makes it easy to write your own exception hierarchy and provides various utilities, among them `boost::exception_ptr`. You can then do:

```
typedef boost::error_info<struct tag_nested_exception, boost::exception_ptr>
    nested_exception;

// ...
catch(...) {
    // better: use BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION
    throw your_exception_type() << nested_exception( boost::current_exception() );
}
```

This is so useful that `boost::diagnostic_info` supports it and will display the nested exception for you (it's undocumented). It's even been suggested that this `nested_exception` `typedef` should be part of the library, too; in the meantime it's easy to write it yourself.

Don't expect magic though: `boost::current_exception` 'captures' the active exception (fine print: or a clone of it) fine only if the throw site used `boost::enable_current_exception`. (Functionally, this is the moral equivalent of using a base exception class that can be cloned). If it didn't, it won't fail but some information may be lost.

---

As a final note, know that the design of Boost.Exception was adopted for C++0x. Thus the following correctly stores the active exception, with none of the `boost::current_exception` caveats since it has language support:

```
// you can still use Boost.Exception:
typedef boost::error_info<struct tag_nested_exception, std::exception_ptr>
    nested_exception;

// ...
catch(...) {
    // e has type std::exception_ptr
    auto e = std::current_exception();
    // internally store the std::exception_ptr
    throw your_exception_type(e);

    // or with Boost
    BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION( your_exception_type() << nested_exception(e) );
}
```

There is also a `std::nested_exception` type that can very easily be used like so:

```
catch(...) {
    // throws an unspecified type derived from your_exception_type
    // and std::nested_exception
    std::throw_with_nested(your_exception_type());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, C++0x keeps surprising me :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could throw a `unique_ptr<some_exception>`, then make `inner_exception` another `unique_ptr` that takes ownership.

Comment: And you have to make sure that only pointers to the same base class gets thrown because this doesn't behave polymorphically.

Comment: @Luc: That certainly is a drawback, isn't it?

Comment: Well, given that `std::unique_ptr` is C++0x, I think there are better alternatives.

Comment: @Luc: `std::unique_ptr` is C++0x, but there are plenty of `unique_ptr` implementations in C++03, under such names as `boost::scoped_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need a class instance property (i.e. `ex`) in Java / C# / C++ if your class is not designed in singleton pattern.  Also, [here](http://www.ozzu.com/cpp-tutorials/tutorial-exceptions-t86515.html) is a tutorial that you might want to take a look.

Comment: The `MyException` class member is used like this:
1. I catch the exception thrown
2. I instantiate **another** exception with a more specific message and set the `ex` property to the exception caught in 1
3. Throw the new exception created.

It is a nice tutorial though, the one you sent me.

Comment: It looks like you wanted to keep it for back reference, right?  Why isn't it an `Exception` instance then?  Besides, if you only want a back reference for keeping the original exception, why don't you simply stack up the trace messages and throw the original exception away?  Probably in the constructor?  It looks more reason to me.  My 2 cents